# Cannot read property 'Direction' of undefined, tests only

Tags: react-native

I just added `TouchableOpacity` to a component and the app is working fine, but my tests, using `react-native-testing-library`, fail to run:

```js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'Direction' of undefined

      at Object.Direction (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/Directions.js:3:39)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/GestureHandler.js:2:1)
```

I just removed and re-added `react-native-gesture-handler` with yarn, and ran `pod install`. Again, the app is working, but the tests fail to run.

I actually get the same error when using `<Text onPress={() => onOptionPress(opt)} />` rather than `TouchableOpacity`.

component:

```js
const SelectOptions = ({ field, dismissOverlay, onOptionPress }) => {
  return (
    <Overlay
      isVisible
      overlayStyle={styles.overlay}
      height={"auto"}
      onBackdropPress={dismissOverlay}
    >
      <View>
        {field.options.map((opt, i) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.option}
            key={i}
            onPress={() => onOptionPress(opt)}
          >
            <Text>{opt}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </Overlay>
  );
};
```

test:

```js
describe("CardFormView", () => {
  let wrapper, birthdayField;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = render(
      <React.Fragment>
        <CardFormView form={form} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    birthdayField = wrapper.getByText("Add a Birthday Gift Card");
  });

  const message1 =
    "...";
  const message2 =
    "...";

  it("shows the options for a birthday card when clicked", () => {
    fireEvent.press(birthdayField);
    expect(wrapper.getByText(message1)).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("sets an option when clicked", () => {
    fireEvent.press(birthdayField);
    const firstOption = wrapper.getByText(message1);
    fireEvent.press(firstOption);
    expect(wrapper.queryByText(message2)).toBeNull();
    expect(wrapper.getByText(message1)).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you install the peer dependency react-test-renderer?

Comment: It's in my project, yes. Adding `import "react-test-renderer";` to the file isn't helping. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 39):

This is because you are not mocking the `react-navigation-gesture-handler`

**To use mock of `react-navigation-gesture-handler` you should add jestSetup.js from node_modules in jest.config.json or jest.config.js**

```
setupFiles: [
  "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
]
```

I found a reference from the following link and It's working for me.

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/344#issuecomment-489547513

Comment: FYI in `react-native-gesture-handler` 1.10.1 this issue is popping up and doesn't appear to be fixable.  Reverting to 1.9.0 for now fixes it.  Reference: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1335#issuecomment-780329005

Answer (score 8):

For me just adding the **setupFiles** didn't work. I added setupFiles and **transformIgnorePatterns** at **"jest"** in **package.json**

Here the code to make the **gestureHandler work**, but I tested it with **AsyncStorage** and the storage stopped work. If you aren't using AsyncStorage I presume this code **will work very well!**

```
"setupFiles": [
     "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
],
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
     "/node_modules/(?!native-base)/"
]
```

My reference:
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/344

Comment: Thanks! I was poking around this for two days!

Answer (score 7):

Updating package.json and reinstalling npm package worked for me.

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@?react-navigation)"],
    "setupFiles": ["./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have to mock the `NativeModules` module from react-native. It can happen with several modules but it was happening to me specifically with the `ImagePicker`, `Linking` and `@react-navigation/native`. This is what I did to mock the native modules.

/src/testSetup.ts

```js
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

NativeModules.RNGestureHandlerModule= {
    attachGestureHandler: jest.fn(),
    createGestureHandler: jest.fn(),
    dropGestureHandler: jest.fn(),
    updateGestureHandler: jest.fn(),
    State: {},
    Directions: {},
},

NativeModules.ImagePickerManager = {
    showImagePicker: jest.fn(),
}

NativeModules.Linking = {
    canOpenUrl: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
    openUrl: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true)
}

NativeModules.Platform = {
    OS: 'iOS'
}

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/animations/TimingAnimation');


const mockNavigation = () => {
    const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();
    const mockedAddListener = jest.fn();

    jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => ({ // @ts-ignore
        ...(jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native')),
        useNavigation: () => ({
          navigate: mockedNavigate,
          addListener: mockedAddListener
        })
      }));
    
    return {mockedNavigate, mockedAddListener}
}
```

in your tests

```js
import { fireEvent, act, render } = '@testing-library/react-native'

const {mockedNavigate, mockedAddListener} = mockNavigation()

test('Should navigate', () => {
  const { queryByText } = render(<Component />)

  fireEvent.press(getByText('View Page Button'))

  expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Your Page Name')
  expect(mockedAddListener).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `react-native-cli` when encountered this problem. I removed it and installed `@react-native-community/cli` instead. It fixed everything!